# Angular 9+ and ng-bootstrap Tooltip fails on fixed elements when a page is scrolled, is there a better hack than mine to fix?

Tags: angular, tooltip, ng-bootstrap

I believe this to be a bug in [ng-bootstrap](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap) and has been [reported](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/3525) and unfortunately there is no information on a fix coming.

I'll add the component html here but my [demo of the issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-bootstrap-tooltip-position-issue) is more useful.

```html
<p>Hover over box 1 for a tooltip and then scroll</p>
<div *ngFor="let item of [].constructor(lineCount); let i = index">{{i}}</div>
<ul 
    class="lhsMenuWrapper show">
    <li
        class='lhsMenuWrapper-item common buttonTop'
        ngbTooltip="Box 1"
        placement="right">
        <h1>1</h1>
    </li>
</ul>
<div 
  class='common buttonTwo'
  ngbTooltip="Box 2"
  placement="right">
  <h1>2</h1>
</div>
```

**GIF of tooltip fail on `position:fixed` elements**

[image]

My hack overrides the tooltip's position attribute with `fixed`, then makes sure its `top` and `left` is positioned correctly and the `width:100%` makes sure the tip is displayed without an early newline (could be improved).

I'm not a fan of this as I don't know the knock on effects, has anyone else come up with a better fix?

```css
.show {
    position: fixed!important;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[Hack demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-bootstrap-tooltip-position-css-hack)

Comment: I was searching for the scrollable issue in ng-boostrap and found in one of the GitHub issues that you only need to put `position: relative` on wrapper (the element with tooltip directive) and it just works.

Comment: @jcubic I just tried adding that property to the ul tag and it didn't work and so I wrapped it in a div with that property and it still didn't work. If you scroll to the bottom of the page you'll the the tooltip. Perhaps it's my version of angular, you can try forking my demo to see if I made a mistake with my wrapper.

Comment: It need to be on li element not on ul, the element that have the tooltip not the container for all your items. This will only work if you put the tooltip on the li element.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue, and ended up putting an outer wrapper around the element with a position: relative.  This seemed to fix the problem.

i.e.

```css
.sidebar {position: fixed;}
.tooltip-wrapper {position: relative;}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <nav>
    <div *ngFor="let item of menuItems" class="tooltip-wrapper">
      <div class="side-nav-item" placement="bottom" ngbTooltip="{{item.tooltip}}">
        <div class="sidebar-icon">
          <i class="{{item.icon}}"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar-title">
          <span>{{item.name}}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I put the parent element like relative element and now it's working.

[image: Code picture]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30569798)

Answer (score 0):

if you use a table just put `style="position: relative"` in your `td`

```
 <td [ngClass]="{'not-expected-value': row.car== null}" style="position: relative">
     <div class="ui-grid-cell-contents dark_backgrd" ngbTooltip="{{row.car?.libelle}}" placement="right">
        <b>{{row.car?.code}}</b>
     </div>
 </td>
```